# Group powershell search results by folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to do something relatively simple with powershell, print the contents of a folder and subfolders underneath that to a text file. In my search to do so I found this page: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/03/list-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-powershell.aspx

Which gives me an example of the command I need: `Get-ChildItem -Path E:\music\Santana -Recurse -File | sort length –Descending` except when the search results are displayed it breaks the contents of one folder and one subfolder out into 4 different sections. i.e. you can see in the example page "e:music\Satana\Shape Shifter" is broken out into two different sections.

How do I "re-group" the search results so if I want to display a folder that has one subfolder it groups by folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sort the folders individually you could do something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\music\Santana -Recurse -Recurse -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object{Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File | Sort-Object Length -Descending }
```

Get every folder and subfolder under that directory Santana and pipe it into `ForEach-Object` where you would then sort the contents of the folder by size. The command you were running is output correctly as you told it to sort everything. The "break-up" you are seeing is just how PowerShell outputs `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects.

Very similar to Briantist example ( since he got his post in before my update ) you can also use the `Group-Object` cmdlets.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\music\Santana -Recurse -File | Sort-Object Length -Descending | Group-Object directory | Select -ExpandProperty group
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path $yourPath -Recurse -File | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Group-Object -Property Directory | ForEach-Object { $_.Group }
```

## How it works

You're already familiar with the first 2 pipeline segments, so let's look at the last 2:

### [`Group-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx)

We group the results based on the `Directory` property. This gives us the groupings we need (run it without the `ForEach-Object` to see what it returns).

### [`For-EachObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx)

Here we just go through each grouping, and return the group (which is itself a collection of the individual file objects).

## Displaying a particular sub-folder:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path $yourPath -Recurse -File | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Group-Object -Property Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -ieq E:\Music\Artist\Whatever } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

or to match on the last part of the path only:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path $yourPath -Recurse -File | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Group-Object -Property Directory | Where-Object { ($_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf) -ieq Whatever } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

Comment: I was about to update my post with a `Group-Object` answer as well. Beat me to it.